# Select only one row to display in the report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

This code is for a button used to print out information for a user. I can display the all data from the datagridview, but I can't display only one row. I would like behavior such that if you click a row, that information will be the only one to display to the crystal report. How can I accomplish this?

```
Private Sub btnPRINT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPRINT.Click

    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("ID").Value, dr.Cells("Permit Date").Value, dr.Cells("Control Number").Value, dr.Cells("Establishment Name").Value, dr.Cells("First Name").Value, dr.Cells("Middle Name").Value, dr.Cells("Last Name").Value, dr.Cells("Address").Value, dr.Cells("Permit Type").Value, dr.Cells("OR Number").Value, dr.Cells("Amount Paid").Value, dr.Cells("Date Paid").Value)
    Next

    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New CrystalReport2
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)


    frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
    frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    frmReport.ShowDialog()
    frmReport.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a report parameter. In Crystal, use whatever field is the unique identifier (possibly ID?) and use it to filter out in the record selection formula. Something like:

```
{yourTable.ID} = {?ID}
```

Comment: Sorry sir, I can't understand that. where do I put it?

Comment: `Report -> Selection Formulas -> Record...`

Comment: Sir! what's the meaning of the question mark before the ID?

Comment: Question marks are automatically added to Parameters. You create one by right clicking "Parameter Fields" in your Field Explorer.

Comment: `{?parameterName}` - in Crystal Reports it means report/subreport parameter. So in his answer @4444 suggests you to filter your report data by specific condition that will select only one (expected) row.

From other point of view you can feed report with already filtered data.